# InsertMany() After Aggregation Pipeline - Not inserting projected fields correcrly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, aggregation-framework

After I run the aggregation the projected fields are returned with res.json but they are not all inserted as new documents. Some of the projected fields are not in the schema (which I'm not sure if you can add anyway) but some fields like `createdAt` are in the schema but refuse to go into the newly created document and instead createdAt is populated with the current date instead of the projected field value.
Here is the code:
Click Schema:

```
const clickSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  page: String,
  clickName: String,
  clickProduct: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 22).replace('T', ' ')},
})
```

PIPELINE:

```
Promise.all(tPromises).then(() => {
    return Visit.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        page: {
          //Random Match Works  
      }
      }  
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "clickData",
        localField: "clickName",
        foreignField: "clickName",
        as: "clickInfo"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$clickInfo'
      }
    },
    {
      // Send these fields from TrackingInfo to Merge
      $project: {
        page: '$page',
        created_at: '$createdAt',
        clickName: $clickName,
        time: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 22).replace('T', ' '),
        randomField: 'randomVal'
      }
    },
  ])
}).then(docs => {
  console.log(docs, 'docs')
   Click.insertMany(docs)
  return res.status(200).json({docs})
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('error:', err)
  return res.status(500).json({err})
});
```

I have tried many different ways of doing this including using a merge in the pipeline instead of `Click.insertMany`.

However, a merge in the pipeline doesn't allow me to `res.json()` any results back (due to either some promise hell or because the pipeline doesn't return an array - I am not 100% sure why.)

Comment: Why not simply do a [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) at the end of aggregation?

Comment: I tried that and it works but I need to return a document to a UI and (to my understanding) when I merge it 'returns' before I can send it back to UI with res.json.